# How to remove Space when using 2 Group Expert(Group By) in crystal report 13.0.7

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal report -13.0.7 in Asp.net mvc application but when i am doing Group By using 2 fields or 1 fields it display space between Group By field and Details Data horizontally.I want to display Group field and detail data field in same line horizontally.Can any one suggest me any solution please.

I shared report screen shot.If you have any query feel free to revert me.

[image]

[image: 2nd Screen Shot when duplicated if second group by changes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 2 groups (`Generic name` and `Dosage From`) i suppose you have putted each field in it's own group header.

In group header of `generic name` you have `generic name field` and in `Dosage From` header you have `dosage from field`. To avoid that, suppress 1st group header (in your case `Generic name` header) and put field `Generic name` into `Dosage From` header. To suppress section, you have to right-click on section and check suppress or in section expert check suppress.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks...you are right First space removed but what about details data. I mean after doing group by 2 it displays space between group by and details data(Second space).

Comment: To avoid that spacing you have to put both field in detail section and do next: select them both -> right-click -> format objects -> check on suppress if duplicated. I think that should do it. Don't forget to suppress then 2nd group header :)

Comment: I did step by step according to your described process. but when Group-2 changes then group-1 repeated(I mean duplicated). I attached another screen shot for your understanding in main question. check second screen shot.

Comment: Then for first field, add additional condition on suppress trigger if <fieldname> = previous(<fieldname>) then true else false. I think that should finally do it :) To add a trigger on field on suppress, right click on field -> format field -> common tab, trigger on suppress (x+2 and pencil icon)

Comment: Can you kindly give any solution about this problem please.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303378/how-to-display-report-header-in-every-page-for-cross-tab-report-in-crystal-repor

Comment: @Badhon i answered, take a look

Comment: @KuKeC  hi...i am facing same problem but my problem not resolve as describe above  can you give detail about how to put trigger on field and what to type in it because when I placed " if <STANDARD_NUMBER> = previous(<STANDARD_NUMBER>) then true else false " condition in formula workshop  where standard_number is name of my field name then it is giving error of formula. I think some gap between my understanding. Can you give detail what should i do.@User5604